# Mysql Group By, Order By, Count, Having Min() combination

Tags: mysql, group-by, having-clause

I have a table with a lot of address records. New data is added to the table and I want to find all the new records that match existing name, postcode, street and which have been assigned to the same client_id (1) along with certain other criteria (result codes). The part I am struggling with is to get the id of the new records which match the existing records.

Existing records have a date_exported int(8) of a date in the past, new records added have a date_exported of 0.

Using the SQL below with MIN around the date_exported field it shows the 0  date_exported records, but the ID's have not sorted with the rest of the SQL due to the grouping and the having. Without the MIN, it shows the correct id and data, but it is for the old records with the date_exported !=0 - I want to find the new records added that have the date_exported = 0

```
SELECT id, name, postcode, street, result_code, MIN(date_exported), COUNT(*) AS cnt 
  FROM fulf.third_party 
 where client_id = '1' 
   and (result_code >= '0' 
   and result_code < '1000' and result_code != '400')  
 GROUP BY name, postcode, street having cnt > 1 order by id asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select t.*
from (
    SELECT name, postcode, street, MIN(date_exported) as MinDate, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM fulf.third_party 
    where client_id = '1' 
        and (result_code >= '0' 
        and result_code < '1000' and result_code != '400')  
    GROUP BY name, postcode, street 
    having cnt > 1 
 ) tm
inner join fulf.third_party t on tm.name = t.name
    and tm.postcode = t.postcode 
    and tm.street = t.street
    and tm.MinDate = t.date_exported
```